# Is possible to pass a string to a style in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an json object in my component like:

```
myCustomStyle =  {
           'name': 'custom',
           'css': 'background-color: black; font-color:white'
}
```

Then in my template I have a div:

```
  <div [ngStyle]="myCustomStyle.css">Test</div>
```

But it not work it gives me an error saying:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object 'background-color' : black; 'font-color': green'
```

What is the correct way to do that with a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `css` should be a object and not a string

```
'css': {'background-color': 'black'; 'color': 'white'}
```

Complete object will look like

```
myCustomStyle =  {
   name: 'custom',
   css:  {
            'background-color': 'black'; 
            'color': 'white'
         }
}
```

**Note** : `font-color` is not a css property which should be `color`

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPPq6pg6c8RQs8aiRvF2?p=preview)**